# Level curves of $f(x,y) : f_x < 0, f_y > 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

I am trying to construct a differentiable, concave function $f(x,y)$ where $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ (but the domain I'll mainly be focussing on is $\mathbb{R}^2_{\geq 0}$) that satisfies $f_x < 0$ and $f_y > 0$.

Query $1:$ What could be a possible construction?

Query $2:$ Which of the following figures below is the correct representation of the level curves of the function?

[image]

Comment: I believe any linear function is convex and concave, so e.g. $f(x,y)=x-y$ should work. Do you need strictly concave or is this an answer?

Comment: @student91 Strictly concave, yes. Your example suggests that figure 2 is correct, but can you think of examples whose level curves look like that in figure 1?

Comment: I believe that for figure 1 you will need that $y=0$ is a level curve, but then $f_y=0$ instead of $f_y<0$ which does not work for you. Another possibility is $f(x,y)\to-\infty$ as $y\downarrow 0$, but then it is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2_{\ge0}$.